How to employ the ES6 tagged template literal query approach of the NPM package `mssql` when executing a `CREATE DATABASE` statement
The Issue
Employing the mssql NPM package, I've noticed an issue when using ES6 Tagged Template Literals with a CREATE DATABASE command.
Running the below, I expect a database with the name my_db to be created.
const dbname = 'my_db';
await pool.request().query`CREATE DATABASE ${dbname}`;

Instead, I get a RequestError with the message

Incorrect syntax near '@param1'

and the stacktrace:
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '@param1'.
    at handleError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:384:15)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Connection.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:957:18)
    at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/handler.js:284:21)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:18:33)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:341:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:278:10)
    at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)

Alternate Attempt 1
const dbname = 'my_db';
await pool.request().query`CREATE DATABASE [${dbname}]`;

Fail. Running the above, a database is created with the name @param1.
Alternate Attempt 2
const dbname = 'my_db';
await pool.request()
    .input('dbname', sql.VarChar, dbname)
    .query('CREATE DATABASE @dbname');

Fail. Running the above, I get a RequestError with message

Incorrect syntax near '@dbname'

and the stacktrace:
RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '@dbname'.
    at handleError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:384:15)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Connection.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:957:18)
    at RequestTokenHandler.onErrorMessage (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/handler.js:284:21)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:18:33)
    at Readable.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:341:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:278:10)
    at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)

Alternate Attempt 3
const dbname = 'my_db';
await pool.request().query(`CREATE DATABASE [${dbname}]`);

Success. Sort of. Running the above, a database is created with the name my_db. The problem with this, however, is we're not parameterizing/sanitizing the name of the database (as is correctly identified by this issue which is a proposal to remove the capability).
Alternate Attempt 4
const dbname = 'my_db';
await pool.request().query`
    DECLARE @_dbname VARCHAR(128) = ${dbname};
    EXEC('CREATE DATABASE ' + @_dbname);`;

Success. This approach dynamically generates the SQL and EXECutes it, but at the cost of having to introduce an additional line of SQL to introduce a second level of abstraction (the @_dbname parameter placeholder) and having to "manually" call on EXEC(...).
Additional Information
I have encountered what appears to be similar behavior when executing for CREATE USER...FOR LOGIN... and CREATE LOGIN...WITH PASSWORD... SQL commands via the mssql package. I have not exhaustively explored each of these like I have for CREATE DATABASE (the alternate attempts written out above). I'm simply trying to start with getting just one of these figured out, first (the CREATE DATABASE) and then go from there.
Obviously, only attempts #3 and #4 successfully create the database. attempt #3 performs no sanitation while attempt #4 does. But attempt #4 feels like more of a work-around than an appropriate solution. Is there a more appropriate or official way to parameterize a CREATE DATABASE SQL query using the mssql package?
This SO post is tangentially associated with my issue.
Software versions

node --version: v20.9.0
npm --version: 10.1.0
Using mssql NPM package v11.0.0
SQL Server:

Product: Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)
Version: 2019 (v15.0.4375.4)


OS: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (10.0)


None of these are really a direct issue as such. SQL Server simply doesn't allow most DDL to be parameterized, you would need to safely inject the names/password etc. Note that attempt #4 isn't actually parameterizing properly, it's just badly constructing the dynamic SQL server-side rather than client-side. You must escape it properly using QUOTENAME or similar.
